# Simple function over twisting data- exercise

Tags: r, function, error-handling, dataset

So I have a given function, that I aim to run over a dataset, but it do not seem to work, with an "error-message" that i quite cannot figure out. I will describe the dataset, because it is twisting, then write my function. The name of the dataset is: cohort_1x1:

```
Year     Age       Male        Female
1940     18        0.001234    0.003028
1940     19        0.005278    0.002098
....     ..        ........    ........   #up to age 100
1940     100       0.004678    0.006548
1941     18        0.004567    0.002753   # start new year, with age 18
1941     19        0.005633    0.001983
....     ..        ........    ........
1979     100       0.003456    0.00256
```

The dataset contains death-rates for Male and Female, for every agegroup 18-100, from year 1940-1979. Further on; the function that i have written is this:

```
gompakmean=function(theta,y_0,h){

#  Returns the expected remaining number of years at age "l_0" under
#  the Gomperz-Makeham model with parameter "theta" (vector).
#  "h" is the time increment for the numerical integration.

l_0=y_0/h
l_e=110/h
ll=(l_0+1):l_e
hh=(theta[2]/theta[3])*(exp(theta[3]*h)-1)
p=exp(-theta[1]*h-hh*exp(theta[3]*ll*h))
P=cumprod(p)
(0.5+sum(P))*h
}
```

This function returns the expected number of years, for every year/agegroup, and it is to be done separately for men and female.
But if i try with input like the one below, i get the following error-message:

```
Input:
s=-c(8,9,2)
theta=exp(s)
y_0 = cohort_1x1$Male
h = 1
gompakmean(theta,y_0,h)
```

Leads to this error-message:

```
[1] 46.13826
Warning message:
In (l_0 + 1):l_e :
numerical expression has 3320 elements: only the first used
```

So get an output for the first year (age?) which is: [1]46.13826.
But then the function seem to stop, hence the error-message. Is the reason somewhat with my dataset? That maybe after running over 1940, it must have year 1941? But that will only give me output for year 18 in every year?
Because my aim is to calculate expected number of years for every agegroup in every year, i.e: calculate expected number of years for every cohort in all the years.

Appreciate all answers!:)

Comment: `l_0` is a vector of length > 1, but `:` expects scalar values (length-one vectors in R) on both sides.

Comment: And you get a warning, not an error.

Comment: I see @Roland, because the length of `y_0` is 3320, so `l_0` simply becomes `l_0 = y_0/h` if h=1 for example, while `l_e` is only a vector of length 110? Then `ll` cannot iterate from 3320:110, that makes no sense? 
But my `y_0` is of length 3320, do you have any idea what I can do? 
Yeah sorry, warning-message

Comment: Sorry, meant `l_e` is only a scalar, while `l_0` is a vector